# Giving arguments in python, straight from command line/ userinput

Tags: python, command-line, arguments, command-line-arguments, raw-input

But I've been trying all kinds of things and I just learn best when given an example, and I can't find any.

First code in snapchat.py

```
def add_friend(self, friend):
    timestamp = self._timestamp()

    data = {
        'action': 'add',
        'friend': friend,
        'timestamp': timestamp,
        'username': self.username
    }

    params = [
        self.auth_token,
        timestamp
    ]

    self.post('/friend', data, params)
```

Second code in test.py

```
 username = raw_input('Enter your username: ')
 password = raw_input('Enter your password: ')
 s.login(username, password)

 s.add_friend()
```

Now obv. this gives me an error, the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 11, in <module>
    s.add_friend()
TypeError: add_friend() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

The point here is, I have no clue how to feed it argument, I suspect "self" (my username) is the first agument, which is given, and the name of the friend is left.

For now I want to be able to have this script ask the user the username and enter it by raw_input.

If anyone could help, that'd be great!

Comment: `self` refers to the instance of the class; in this case the variable `s`.  Your `add_friend` method is encased by a class, right?

Comment: yes, it is. I got it working.
I added this line: friend = raw_input('Enter friend name: ')
Then changed this line: s.add_friend() to: s.add_friend(friend)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those wondering.

I added this line: friend = raw_input('Enter friend name: ') Then changed this line: s.add_friend() to: s.add_friend(friend)